# How can I access All Files inside device of specific type (e.g image, audios, videos) etc in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, file, filesystems, picker

I want to make my own media picker, where I will open screen and show all images of device in case of image picker, show all audios on the device in case of audio picker and all videos for video picker. The method must work on both android and IOS. I am using flutter Dart to do this. I am new in flutter and any help will be highly appricated.

I have tried Flutter File manager and unable to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package available named [File Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) have look into it. Its very well documented.

Comment: I don't want to use build in file picker. I want to create my own file picker and want to access all files by extension from device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager) package for this purpose.